# no install button on ubuntu software centre

Tags: software-center

Hi I got a cd from a friend with Linux operating systems on.
I chose ubuntu. not sure which version but he said he got the cd on a magazine last year.

when i go to software centre to install software i cant install anything because ther is no install button. only buttons for the ones you have to pay for. can you please help me?

this is my first time using ubuntu and i really like it accept for this problem because i need to install plugins in order to play videos.

thanks andrew

Comment: Do you have an icon the shape of little gear in the right top corner?  If there is click on it, and choose About This Computer, and include the Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. It turned out I was set for the Mexican server. Go to system settings, select "Software and Updates" and then on the "Ubuntu Software" Tab make sure that your "Download From" Setting is "Main Server" or possibly "Server for United States".
The first time you use the Software centre after this you will have to click the more info button on an app. It will then say that this is available on another source. Click the use this source. Walk away for a while since this action seems to update everything, but takes a little while.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the top left of this picture and you will get it:

[image]

---

[Solved] firstly navigate to system-> administration-> software sources

then go to update and at the bottom of the window their is an option to select what type of update you want. select -normal update- the close the window and reload.

The problem should be fixed.